# BubbleSort with Assembler

Tags: assembly, 68000

So for my assignment I'm supposed to write BubbleSort in assembler. I based my assembler code on this Java BubbleSort loop. For some reason assembler keeps thinking that Arrays A and B are one big array and tries to sort the whole thing. I can't seem to get it to stop sorting once it's done with A and start over again with B.

```
while (Done == 0) 
{  
  Done = 1;          // 1 represents true.
  i = 0;
  while ( i < N-k)
  { 
    if (A[i] > A[i+1])
    { 
      Help = A[i];
      A[i] = A[i+1];
      A[i+1] = Help;
      Done = 0;          // Not sorted...
    }
    i++;
  }
  k = k + 1;
}
```

Here's the Assembler code. The formatting got a little messed up but hopefully it's still readable.

```
Start:
move.l #A, D0
move.l #5, D1
bsr    BubbleSort   * Sort array A

move.l #0, i

Print1: 
move.l #5, D0
move.l i, D5  
cmp.l  i, D0
beq    Start2 **********

move.l #A, A0
move.l i, D0
muls  #4, D0
move.l  0(A0, D0.w), D0
jsr    WriteInt

addi.l  #1, i
bra    Print1

Start2:
move.l #str, A0  ************
move.l #5, D0
jsr    WriteLn

move.l #B, D0
move.l #10, D1
bsr    BubbleSort   * Sort array B

move.l #0, i

Print2:
move.l #10, D0
cmp.l  i, D0
beq    Stop

move.l #B, A0
move.l i, D0
muls  #4, D0
move.l  0(A0, D0.w), D0
jsr    WriteInt

addi.l  #1, i
bra    Print2

*D0 = address of int array to be sorted
*D1 = N

BubbleSort:
movea.l #A, A0
move.l #0, i
move.l #0, D    *Done is 0
move.l D, D2   *pass Done to D2
move.l D1, N  *N is number of elements
move.l #0, k

WhileStart:
cmp.l #0, D2  * compare if D2 == 0
BNE WhileEnd  *if not 0, go to WhileEnd
move.l #1, D2   * D2=1
move.l #0, i  * i = 0
move.l i, D3    *pass i to D3
move.l k, D4    * pass k to D4
move.l N, D7    * pass N to D7
sub.l D4,D7     * D7 = N-k

WhileStart2:
cmp.l D7, D3    *Compare i with N-k
BGE   WhileEnd2 
move.l i, D3
muls #4 D3
move.l 0(A0, D3.w), D5  *D5 = A[i]
move.l i, D4  
add.l #1, D4    *i+1
muls #4, D4
move.l 0(A0, D4.w), D6  *D6 = A[i+1]

IfStart:
cmp.l D6, D5    *compare A[i] with A[i+1]
BLE IfEnd
move.l D5, 5000 * pass A[i] to memory location 5000
move.l D6, 0(A0, D3.w) *A[i] = A[i+1]
move.l 5000, 0(A0, D4.w)  *A[i+1] = whatever was at location 5000 (old A[i])
move.l #0, D2       * D2=0 again
move.l i, D3     * passing i to D3
bra IfEnd   *End of If loop

IfEnd:
move.l i, D3    *i++
add.l #1, D3
move.l D3, i
bra WhileStart2    *Go back and compare i with N-k

WhileEnd2:
move.l k, D4    *k = k + 1
add.l #1, D4
move.l D4, k
bra WhileStart  * go back

WhileEnd:
rts *** I have added a rts to make sure your function returns....
```

Comment: What assembler is this?

Comment: Assembler code for which architecture, this is not x86 - that's for sure. Kind of crucial information to include in the question and tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is M68K assembly.  Here's a nice reference: http://wpage.unina.it/rcanonic/didattica/ce1/docs/68000.pdf

I see two semantic bugs in your code:

1) Inside your bubble sort routine, you never use the value that the caller has placed in D0.  You are actually hardcoding the address of the array to be A with the first statement:

```
    movea.l #A, A0
```

This will keep array B from ever being sorted.  I'd recommend replacing this with:

```
    move.l D0, A0
```

2) Your addressing of the elements includes an extra factor of 2.  For instance, you're using D4 as an index register off of A0 in this snippet:

```
    muls #4, D4
    move.l 0(A0, D4.w), D6  *D6 = A[i+1]
```

The "Address Register Indirect with Index" addressing mode (sec 2.2.8 in http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) will already scale the contents of your index register (D4) by 2, based on the 32-bit operand size (i.e. ".l" in move.l) and 16-bit index register spec (i.e. ".w" in D4.w).  So, your muls instruction should only multiply by 2.  Better yet, you could omit the muls instruction and simply change "D4.w" to "D4.l".

It looks like all of your accesses into the arrays have this same x2 indexing error.  Assuming that you have A and B declared in adjacent memory locations, this x2 indexing error will cause your sort routine, when called for A, to access the elements of B, of course imposing some partial ordering on both arrays in the process.  And this will look like your sort routine is sorting both A and B at the same time.